# Clean up. Is [jsfiddle] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, clean-up

I noticed some users absing the [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) tag. Linking to jsfiddle code. Therefore making a case for perhaps removing the tag [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually cleaned up this tag a while ago, leaving only around 10 questions left with it. There *are* some valid questions about jsFiddle that deserve the tag. jsFiddle is a programming tool and there are some cases where it can be difficult or confusing for some people using it, so questions about it are valid. However, the tag is widely misused to indicate "I have a jsFiddle example in my question."

So, yes it is useful, and yes, it does appear to need cleaning again.

Comment: So about 7 % of the tag is valid (141 tags total). If jsfiddle is in the title and the question is tagged javascript the relevant questions would still be searchable.

Comment: 93% is abuse, I'd say revove the tag.

Comment: @OlofEdler Searchable, but not in the same way. Maybe if the popup/etc. had info saying not to use it just because you made a fiddle?

Comment: @Olof: That was also back when the tag only had ~30 questions to begin with. Going through it now, there are a decent number of questions that use the tag appropriately.

Comment: @animuson. If the tag was renamed to [jsfiddle-page] the tag would likely be less abused. I think now it can't be many questions not already asked that really deserve the tag [jsfiddle].

Comment: Perhaps the tag wiki excerpt could open with something explicitly indicating that the tag should be used for asking questions about how to use the jsFiddle application?  Might help (if anyone ever reads the excerpts before just clicking that tag).

Answer (score -1):

To vote on. If you like me think the tag is mostly useless. And you don't see the point of keeping it since people abuse it.

Comment: Don't worry, this is meta, we'll vote on your question instead :)